# How many levels does Asterix on SNES have?

Tags: asterix

I've recently bought Asterix on the SNES, and it's kinda hard. I'd like to know if I'm getting close to the end of the game, but I can't find this information on the Internet. :(

Any help?

Comment: As I remember, the last level is the one where you have to find Obelix, Act **V-VI**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember, the last level is the one where you have to find Obelix, it's 
**Act V-VI**

just after the **V-V** which is the level in the roman temple with waterfalls in the background.